# How to create Android layouts for major devices?

Tags: android, galaxy, motorola

Iam developing an Android app which should compatible for the following devices,

> **Device Name    =>    Resolution ; Screen size**
>
> Samsung Galaxy S4   => 1080x1290 ; 5.0”
>
> Galaxy Nexus    => 720x1280 ; 4.7”
>
> Nexus 4     => 768x1280 ; 4.7”
>
> Motorola Droid Razr M   =>     540x960  ;  4.3”
>
> Nexus S         => 480x800 ;   4”
>
> Galaxy S2   =>     480x800  ;  4.3”
>
> Galaxy Ace  =>     320x480  ; 3.5”
>
> Galaxy Note     => 800x1280    ;  5.3”
>
> Galaxy Note II      => 720x1280    ; 5.5”
>
> Nexus 10    => 2560 x 1600  ; 10.1”
>
> Galaxy Tab 10.1         => 1280*800    ; 10.1”
>
> Galaxy Note 8.0         => 1280*800 ;  8.0”
>
> Galaxy Tab 7.7      =>  1280*800    ; 7.7”
>
> Nexus 7         =>  1280*800   ; 7.0”
>
> Galaxy Tab      =>  1024*600   ; 7.0”

How can i create suitable layouts for all these kind of devices ? How many layouts i need to create for this application ?

Can any one please help me .... :(

Answer (score 1):

Official guides are pretty good:

- [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
- [A sample project that supports multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)
- [9 Patch approach to designing the UI](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 layouts one for phones and one for phablets.
Be sure to make these layouts scaleable so that it looks nice on all devices.

Every screen size has multiple buckets for pixel densities. These are ldpi mdpi hdpi xhdpi. These buckets should contain images in according to their sizing percentage:

ldpi: 75%
mdpi: 100%
hdpi: 150%
xhdpi: 200%

So an image of 225 width in the mdpi bucket should have a 450 pixels in width on xhdpi.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

Use in res/values-xlarge/ with Boolean value

true
In res/values use

false
boolean tabletDeviceSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTabletDevice);

if (tabletDeviceSize) {

//use tablet support layout

} else

{

//another layout for mobile support

}

As per android supporting screen

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html,

res/values-sw600dp can also be used.

(for 600dp wide tablet and bigger).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 4 sets of layouts for your application - nexus one, 320×480, 7 inch and 10 inch.. these will map to all the phone sizes

Comment: Device types, screen resolutions and screensizes should be kept apart. Android devides layouts by density pixels and screen size.